# Set active to bootstrap nav class

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a bootstrap navbar and i want to set active class for another li element when i click on it.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-default" >
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a>Content</a></li>
      <li><a>News</a></li>
      <li><a>Subject</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.navbar-nav li').click(function() {
    $('.navbar li').removeClass('active');
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
        $this.addClass('active');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Not working, i'm new in javascript. I think i might be declaring the class element wrong and jQuery doesnt recongnize my script.

Comment: And what is the problem in the code? Is event handler run on click of `li`? Is jQuery loaded before using it? Is the `script` loaded in `<head>`? See [mcve]

Comment: Doesnt change the state of my li element @Tushar

Comment: It works fine.. no idea what's your problem

Comment: I'm using a single-page-app. I declare this script inside my html

Answer (score 3):

It works with `data-toggle="tab"` activate a tab without javascript.

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-default" >
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab">Content</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab">News</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab">Subject</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: it also a good solution, but as you have embedded a jQuery in your question, i try to do specifically with both html + jQuery..

Answer (score 0):

please find attached code.

```
<nav class="navbar" style="cursor:pointer;">
 <div class="navbar-default">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navUl">
        <li class="active"><a>Content</a></li>
        <li><a>News</a></li>
        <li><a>Subject</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

and jquery is:

```
$('#navUl > li').click(function () {

    //Check for active class
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {

        // Remove the active class
        $("li.active").removeClass("active");

        // active current/clicked li
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

i just add id as identifier for jquery,

you can use your class too.